# Want to send ajax request in wordpress to a custom file in plugin

Tags: ajax, post-meta

Want to call a function in my plugin to delete the post-meta on click of a button. How can get this functionality. I suppose it can be done with ajax but i am unable to send ajax request to my custom file in my plugin.

This is html:

```
<button type="button" class="remove_download" style="margin-left:9px;width:80px" value="<?php echo $meta_id;?>">Remove</button>
```

my hook for adding the script file:

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugins_url( 'inc/myscript.js', __FILE__ ), array(), false, true );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
```

my script file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".remove_download").click(function(){
    var meta_id  = jQuery(this).val();  
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'functions.php',
        data:{'meta_id':meta_id},
        success:function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
    });
```

});

I want to send the request on functions.php (In my plugin folder or myplugin.php who has a function called:

```
function remove_post_mete($meta_id){
          delete_post_meta($meta_id, 'my-meta-key');
 }
```

How can i call to above function or my functions.php in my plugin folder.

Need help to get this done.

Comment: No, you don' want to ;) Use WP's AJAX API in correct way...

Comment: Have a read of the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins